# System of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the system of equations 
$$x+y+2z=a$$
$$x+z=b$$
$$2x+y+3z=c$$
show that for this system to be consistent, the constant $a,b$ and $c$ must satisfy $c=a+b$

Comment: Add the first two equations and the result should be the third equation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $ x+x+y+2z+z=a+b$ this is the third equation namely $2x+y+3z=c$ therefore we get $a+b=c$